# Can't use pip without saying py -m pip

Tags: python

It says `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python38\python.exe" "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified."`, when I use `pip` alone.

Comment: Could you please list your python installations and paths using `py -0p`?

Comment: Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64        C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe *

Comment: Use `where pip` to find the broken installation and then delete it and/or remove it from PATH. Also note you have to close and reopen your terminal for PATH updates to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an issue with an old Python installation that wasn't fully removed.

An easy way to resolve it is by overwriting the system `PATH` variable.

Press Winkey+Break (or Winkey+Pause depending on keyboard), go to "advanced system settings" then "environment variables".

On user variables you have "path". Edit it and add this new path:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`

Move this all the way to the top and press OK.

Reopen your cmd. Should work.

Comment: I just noticed my [Microsoft keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/wired-keyboard-600/anb-00001) doesn't have a Break key.  I find that kind of odd.

Comment: Hello,  thank you for the help, but it is already there.

Comment: @MarkRansom Press "pause" instead. They're equivalent.

Comment: @jams If it's all the way at the top (you must move it manually by clicking "move up" repeatedly), try adding it to the system variable path.

Comment: @jams it's not just whether it's there, but where it is in the list.  Move it to the front as suggested by the answer.

Comment: @jams and make sure you re-open your cmd.

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall python, and than you install python, must choice pip.